# Prove that if $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$, then $F'(x)=f(t)$ if $x\in (a,b)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b)\to \mathbb R$ continuous. Let $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$. I want to prove that $F'(x)=f(x)$.  I know the following theorem :

> **Theorem :** Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ continuous and $G(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$. Then $G$ is $\mathcal C^1[a,b]$ and $G'(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in(a,b)$.

So my exercise looks quite obvious knowing this theorem, but I guess that the fact that $f:[a,b)\to \mathbb R$ is a bit different.

Can I do as follow : Let $a<x<\xi<b$ and $f_\xi:[a,\xi]\to \mathbb R$ defined by $f_\xi=f|_{[a,\xi]}$. $$G(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt=\int_a^x f_\xi(t)dt.$$ By the theorem I wrote : $G'(x)=f_\xi(x)=f(x)$. Since $x\in [a,b)$ is unspecified, the result follow.

**Question** Is it the way to solve this problem or I really do thing more complicated ?

Answer (score 1):

The looks correct to me. You are trying to prove for any $x \in [a,b)$ that $F'(x) = f(x)$, so for brevity you could lay out the proof like so

Let $x \in [a,b)$ and notice
\begin{align}
F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt = \int_a^x f \rvert_{[a,x]}(t) dt
\end{align} 
so $F'(x) = f \rvert_{[a,x]}(x) = f(x)$ where the first equality follows from the stated Theorem.

Comment: Something looks strange, how would you define $\lim_{y\to x^+}\int_a^y f|_{[a,x]}(t)dt$ ?

Comment: I don't think I need to - having fixed $x \in [a,b)$ I'm making statements only at the point $x$, rather than the entire domain $[a,b)$.

Comment: To give sense to $F'(x)$, the point $x$ has to be in an open set where $F$ has to be well defined.

Comment: You're right, maybe the following works better:

Let $x \in [a,b)$ and $\xi \in (x,b)$ and notice

$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt = \int_a^x f\rvert_{[a,\xi]}(t) dt$

so $F'(x) = f\lvert_{[a,\xi]}(x) = f(x)$ where the first equality holds by the stated Theorem.

Comment: it's exactly what I have made ;)

Comment: In that case we agree that you're right ;)